# How to make list files in a directory and download them using php

Tags: php, html, css

I am developing an online system for students so i need them to download notes or assignments uploaded by lectures.I am using PHP and wrote this script that displays files but i need the files to be downloadable once a user clicks it. 
I have attached an example of how i want the list to be.

**Below is a code that i wrote.**

```
if ($handle = opendir('./propics')) {

while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

        echo "$entry <br>";
    }
}

closedir($handle);
```

Comment: your echo "$entry <br>"; needs to be echo "http://path-to-server/"."$entry <br>";

Comment: its printing the path

Comment: right, when you echo it in the browser, it will print the path to the file with the br tag, it will display the world accessible link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is attribute download for newer browsers:

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

this line will download image on click. It would work for any extension.

you just have to echo your file like this:

```
echo '<a href="' . $file . '" download>download' . ' $file</a>';
```

here is the link: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Thanks this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You have an unmatched curly bracket. Try this snippet.

```
   <?php

    if ($handle = opendir('./scripts')) {

      while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

          echo '<a href="' . $entry . '" download>download' . ' $entry</a>';
        }
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys i have managed to make it work with your help, all that is left is the styling with css.

here is the final code:

```
echo '<a href="/prac/admin/'.$entry.'"' .'download="'.$entry.'">'.$entry.'</a>'.'<br>';
```